# Make a bootstrap datepicker from a pop-up to inline

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I used [this](http://codepen.io/Yuping/pen/xqrjE) datepicker and it works fine, but I can't find how to display the contents of this datepicker in a `<div>` without the pop.

My code:

```html
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
      startDate: new Date(),
      minDate: 0,
      language: "fr",
      autoOpen: true,
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true 
    }).datepicker('update', new Date());
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I can't get the value date from the input

```html
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input" class="form-control">

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();
  jQuery('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
    jQuery('#my_hidden_input').val( jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
      startDate: new Date(),
      language: "fr",
      autoOpen: true,
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
      //datesDisabled: ['22/02/2017', '28/02/2017']
    }).datepicker('update', new Date());;
  });

  jQuery("input[type=hidden]").bind('change', function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).val());
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#inline-or-embedded) say:

> Instantiating the datepicker on a simple div will give an embedded picker that is always visible.

Here a working sample:

```js
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    minDate: 0,
    language: "fr",
    autoOpen:true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true 
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
  
  jQuery('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {
    jQuery('#my_hidden_input').val(e.date);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js"></script>

<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input" class="form-control">
```

**EDIT:**

You are adding the the [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#events) listner in the wrong place, put it after `datepicker` initialization. Moreover [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#events) event has the `date` property that contains Date object representing the selected date.

Comment: Yes is that's it, but i want to get the value of date from the input, i putted it on hiden like a doc but i can't do an alert on it

Comment: Glad my example and link to docs helped, what is the problem with alert? What are you trying to achieve? If you have a complete different problem maybe you can ask a new question.

Comment: i want to the date from the hidden input when i click on the datepicker

Comment: @user7616808 I've updated my answer to address the other requirement. Please use correct indentation when posting code on StackOverflow.